# using getEdges() function on OrientVertex in a server side javascript function

Tags: javascript, orientdb2.2

In my OrientDB Graph database I have a javascript serverside function with the following code:

```
var sql = "SELECT FROM COMMITTREES WHERE hash=? LIMIT 1";
var results = db.command("sql",sql,[hash]);
var vertex = results[0];
```

According to the documentation, the `db.command()` returns an array of `OrientVertex`. In the `OrientVertex` [documentation](http://orientdb.com/javadoc/latest/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/impls/orient/OrientVertex.html#getEdge-com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientBaseGraph-com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument-java.lang.String-com.orientechnologies.common.util.OPair-java.lang.Object-com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.OIdentifiable-java.lang.String:A-) I find a lot of usefull functions. For example, the `countEdges()` [function](http://orientdb.com/javadoc/latest/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/impls/orient/OrientVertex.html#countEdges-com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Direction-java.lang.String...-)

This function seems to be accessible for use in server side javascript, but it requires a parameter of type `iDirection`. Now, my question is how this `iDirection` is wrapped on server side, how can I make use of the `countEdges()` function in serverside javascript?

```
var count = vertex.countEdges(WHAT GOES HERE?);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the full qualified name of the enum. So somethng like

```
var count = vertex.countEdges(com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Direction.OUT, someLabel):
```

Same concept applies to any other method - the javascript to java integration works pretty well in general. You can call into any methods as long as they are reachable somehow from the top level db object.

Hope that helps.

...And, yes, server side functions are pretty handy.

Comment: Yes, this works! For sure server side javascript is super handy, but finding the right documentation is quite hard. Now that I know I can use the full qualified name, things might go a lot smoother. Maybe this simple tip should be added to the docs?

Comment: Yes, I agree. It’s hard to find good docs or examples on this feature on the orientdb site itself  - but their assumption is likely that we’re familiar with the Nashorn engine. For example, you can find some docs at https://github.com/shekhargulati/java8-the-missing-tutorial/blob/master/10-nashorn.md but there’s other docs as well on Nashorn. You can even do clever things like: var HashMap = Java.type("java.util.HashMap"); var userAndAge = new HashMap()

Comment: Also see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-nashorn-2126515.html